# Page Up & Page Down don't work in tmux when SSHed from Mac

Tags: macos, ssh, tmux

I work on a Mac, using the Terminal to SSH into a Linux box. On the Linux box I have tmux 1.6.

I cannot get page up or page down to work correctly. If I am not running tmux, when I hit <kbd>Page Up</kbd> the screen scrolls up correctly. However, when I am in tmux, <kbd>Page Up</kbd> moves the window above the tmux contents. That is, it does not scroll the tmux contents; it scrolls the tmux window up (and, if I hit <kbd>Page Up</kbd> enough,  off the screen).

I have played with a lot of options in `.tmux.conf`, but I just cannot pin this down.

```
cat ~/.tmux.conf
#set -g history-limit 100000
# Sane scrolling
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
#set -g terminal-overrides ",*:XT@"
set -g mode-mouse on
```

As you can see, I tried several Terminal overrides. The current terminal overrides works perfectly if I am using PuTTy on a Windows computer, but nothing I have tried modifies the behavior when I am logging in from my Mac.

Answer (score 27):

When you're in a tmux session, you can't page up and page down normally. You must hit the prefix key (<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> by default) followed by <kbd>PageUp</kbd> (which is <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd> on a Mac keyboard), and then you'll be in "copy-mode", where you can <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> to your heart's content.

See the tmux man page for more info: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1